# how can i create a right user in xampp's mysql to communicate with my program on the VPS

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

recently i create school project which was web app that has tomcat as server and use mysql database, it work properly in my local system but when i want to run it on my vps, i get this error:

[the err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMyRN.png)

i had the same problem when i try to clone my project to my friend's computer, and we solve it by create the user (admin@localhost) by phpmyadmin in his computer, but i cant solve this problem when i create user in my vps's phpmyadmin.

this is my app's property to connect to DB:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/normalizedDB
jdbc.username = admin
jdbc.password = admin
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

and this is my db on xampp and the open ports at my vps:

[info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtTT.png)

plz tell me how can i create that 'admin' user

I added this lines separately to my.cnf to handle all ipv6 things and give all priviledge to admin@localhost but still tomcat says 'HTTP Status 500 Could not open connection' and i have to say that my db has data too ...

```
bind-address="127.0.0.1"
bind-address = ::1
bind-address = ::
bind-address = 'localhost'
```

Comment: First of all , if you are running your webapp(which works fine in your local system) from a VPS , did you have install MySQL or Maria DB server in VPS and ported your dump in vps? Or you want to connect your VPS  to connect the DB in your local machine ? Kindly make clear.

Answer (score 0):

Doube colons **" :: "** are for tcp6 , that is IPv6. For a IPv4 there will be only one colon before port **" : "**.

Comment: tnx, could u tell me how can i set xampp's mysql to listen on localhost instead of what it has now in ipv6 form?

Comment: or how can i set my web app's property to 'localhost' instead of '::' ???

Comment: or how can i set my web app's property to '0.0.0.0' instead of '::' ???

Comment: Do you  mean you want to know how to set up  webapp in your VPS ?

Comment: somehow, i set up tomcat correctly but the xampp's mysql doesn't respond to webapp ...

Comment: if your tomcat setup is correct then , in your browser when u call http://<VPS IP here>:8080/ , you can see tomcat page. Then its ok. Latter for mysql, I prefer to install mysql-server. Well in your case , both the tomcat and mysql ports are up and running. Only problem is they are not bind to tcp insted in tcp6.  Do your application have specified the IPv6 socket usage ? I doubt so.

Comment: Are you sure , you have imported mysql dump to xamp mysql. DO your xamp having your database with data. Failing to do so and if your application is written such a way that  initialise with the database with table then also error could be thrown.

Comment: Everything about tomcat and mysql's data are Okey and i see the tomecat and my static pages but I didn't do anything about bind my application to ipv6 socket, could u tell me how should I set the property to be able to connect to ipv6 socket?